# Why CloudRun instance count could jump very high, especially during redeployment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, knative

When using CloudRun, why my instance count jumps very high during redeployment? My CloudRun application has very low CPU utilization and the traffic is extremely low as well. I would expect during a redeployment the instance count should just go up to 2 (one is new, one is old, still running for a while before all traffic goes to the new one)

Also, is there a way to control a "rollingUpdate" behavior during deployment?

[image: instance count high during deployment]

[image: instance count and CPU utilization across 7 days]

[image: requests rate across 7 days]

Comment: The graphs reveal very little information except your containers take too long to startup. Edit your question and show the logs.

Comment: Multiple containers are created, so what logs would matter in this case? My container starts pretty fast, as most start within 4 sec (last graph). But no matter they start a bit faster or slower, why would cloud run scale them to 10+ instances?

Comment: I am sorry, I read 4 minutes - 4 seconds is great. Review the logs and figure out why multiple containers are being started. Based on the lack of details in your question, I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks, I looked again at the logs, there is nothing special but I noticed that what we first do a `gcloud run replace`, then do a `gcloud run update --revision-suffix xxx`, because the replace command doesn't take --revision-suffix as a parameter. Could this causing some issues?